# how to write a script when table > tr > td[data-value] is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have div based drop-down and its value stored in TD[data-value]. i want to write script when that TD data-value changed.
**below the format of td :**

```
<td data-value="some-id">
<div class="dropdown">some elements</div>
</td>
```

I try that

```
$("table tr td:eq(1)[data-value]").change(function(){
//
}
```

but not working

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: sorry. i cant understand @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event handler works only with input elements. You may do like this:

```
if($("table tr td:eq(1)[data-value]") != 'some-id'){
   console.log('changed');
}
```

When the value would be changed? May be you do like this:

```
$("table tr td:eq(1)[data-value]").click(function(){
   $(this).data('value') == 'some-id' ? 'other-value' : 'some-id';
   //here you may do other stuff as above...
});
```

Comment: i have some-id from mvc html helper so cannot get that

Answer (score 0):

Change event should bind directly to the div whose value is changed

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td data-value="some-id">
          <div>some elements</div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

$("table > tbody > tr > td[data-value='some-id'] > div").change(function(){
      //changed
    alert();
});                                                    


$('div').trigger("change");
```

[Check this here fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbws5dv9/)

Comment: @Saravanan Arunagiri check the fiddle link. It is working

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) in modern browsers

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName = 'data-value') {
      snippet.log('value of ' + mutation.target.id + ' changed to: ' + $(mutation.target).attr('data-value'))
    }
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true
};

$('td[data-value]').each(function() {
  observer.observe(this, config);
});

//to test
$('input').change(function() {
  $('td[data-value]').eq($(this).data('index')).attr('data-value', this.value)
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-value="some-id" id="1">
      <div class="dropdown">some elements</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-value="some-id" id="2">
      <div class="dropdown">some elements</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--to change the value of attribute change the input value-->
<input data-index="0" />
<input data-index="1" />
```

Comment: is **observer.observe()** supporting not only the Chrome browser.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara for older browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: thank you few moths ago i have heard that it's supported by only on browser may be it was Chrome or Firefox